# Firefox address bar suggests wrong domain

Tags: firefox

I recently upgraded to FF4 and want to change the behavior of the address bar.  Right now if I start to type, for example, "websitename", it will suggest every url with 'websitename' in it.  So far so good.

If I start by typing "local-websitename" {I use the local- prefix for sites I'm developing on my local server} it doesn't narrow the suggested list to that subdomain.  It still suggests every 'websitename' it has in the history.

I keep ending up going to the live site when I mean to be on the local site, and vice-versa.  I am pretty sure the behavior used to be that if you started typing a specific subdomain, it wouldn't suggest other subdomains (or at least, not at the top of the list) over the one that was specified.

Any ideas on how to change this behavior back?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at browser.urlbar.matchBehavior property in about:config (as well as all browser.urlbar.* properties).

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.matchBehavior

Options 2 or 3 might be what you want.

Comment: It looks like option 3 is it!  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a local hosts file, e.g.:

```
192.168.0.[your-ip]      www.example.com example.com
xxx.xxx.xxx.[live-ip]    www.example.com example.com
```

Then get a host switcher for Firefox, e.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hostadmin/ to switch between the live and the development environment.

I admit this is not the answer you were expecting, however, in developing this way you are less likely to have surprises when you go live due to the development URL accidentally being hard-coded in a file/database field.

Comment: This isn't really an option for me -- I often have one window with all my local development tabs in it, and another full of live site tabs.  I need to be able to get to both sets at all times.

Comment: ...I get around that problem with a virtual machine running IE and bridged network adaptor.